# Update Two Way Bound value $onDestroy in Angular 1.5 Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I am creating a series of dynamic form components using AngularJS 1.5.

I'm using ng-if to show and hide a form compoenent. When the component is destroyed, I remove it from and array in it's parent, but I also want to set the value of the two way bound object that I have passed in to null.

The below is a simplified version of the code I am using:

```
app.component('textInput', {
    bindings: {
        model: '='
    },
    require: {
        parent:'^formPanel'
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/form/formFields/textInput/textInputView.html',
    controller: function() {

        var self = this; 

        this.$onInit = function() {
            this.parent.addField(this);
        },
        this.$onDestroy = function() {
            this.model = null;
            console.log(this);
            this.parent.removeField(this);
        }
    }
});
```

This logs the value as null, but outside the scope of the component, angular hasn't registered the change and I am unable to run a digest cycle because there is already one in progress for the $onDestroy event.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a callback to achieve this.

So a function similar to this in the parent scope (this is the callback):

```
$scope.setMyModel = function(val){
  $scope.myModel = val;
};
```

And this in the component HTML file to pass the callback to the component:

```
<test-input
  my-model="myModel"
  my-callback="setMyModel " 
/>
```

And this in the component's bindings to collect the callback:

```
bindings: {
  myModel: '=',
  myCallback: '='
},
```

Followed by a call to the callback in the $onDestroy function:

```
this.$onDestroy = function() {
  this.myCallback(null);
  this.parent.removeField(this);
}
```

There may be a better way, but this will ensure that the parent scope is always in control of setting the value that `myModel` holds.